# How would I recreate this arched pillar from Vanishing Realms?

Tags: mesh

This is from the first room in Vanishing Realms:

[image]

The part I am concerned with is the top section that goes from a straight column to this kind of splayed out effect, not sure of the correct term. Anyways in SolidWorks you would loft this in a couple of seconds, how can I do this in Blender?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try with booleans, subtracting cylindric shapes from a cube gives some similar (rough)  shape... at least for the upper part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Final result:**

[image: final]

### Modeling:

It's extremely simple.

Just add a *Cube*. Go to *Edit Mode*. Select bottom face and extrude (hit <kbd>E</kbd>) it down in the Z axis, after extrude - scale it down (hit <kbd>S</kbd>). Repeat for every segment.

[image: 2]

After that make object *Smooth* and add *Autosmooth* or *Edgesplit Modifier*.